# React Native OAuth TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorize')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0

*(The other similar issues on stackoverflow did not resolve my problem).*

When I try to call `authorize` (a function from the react-native-app-auth library) I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorize')".

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, Button, Linking } from "react-native";

import { authorize } from 'react-native-app-auth';

export default function App() {
  const config = {
    issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
    clientId: 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_APP_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    redirectUrl: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.GOOGLE_OAUTH_APP_GUID:/oauth2redirect/google',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
  };
  
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(authorize); // line 1; this line shows a function present
      const result = await authorize(config); // line 2
      console.log('Authorization Response', result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Hey! Theres an authorization error', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title={"google"}
        onPress={() => handleLogin()}
        key={"google"}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is what I've tried and found out:

I've done `npm install react-native-app-auth`. I ran the react-app using `npm run web`. The error is coming from calling `authorize` in the line marked as 'line 2' inside of the `handleLogin` function.

I've done console.log on 'line 1' to see what if there is some function present there, and there is;

```
f authorize(_ref4) {
  var issuer = _ref4.issuer,
    redirectUrl = _ref4.redirectUrl,
    clientId = _ref4.clientId,
    clientSecret = _ref4.clientSecret,
    scopes = _ref4.scopes,
    _ref4$useNonc…
```

So why is it saying `authorize` is undefined?

Adding `clientSecret` inside of `config` doesn't fix it either. I've tried every fix I can think of, so I don't know what is going wrong. I would appreciate any help on this.

Here are the versions of my packages:

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.72.6",
"react-native-app-auth": "^7.1.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
```

If there's any other information I haven't mentioned which would be helpful for this, I'll be happy to provide it. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/87

Comment: there isn't any manual installation option on the github page anymore

Comment: I didn't, I just ended up using a different library.